# Blazor wasm - how to display file upload progress without copying data into another stream

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm in the process of creating a component to upload some files uploaded by a user to an API. About 10 files ranging from 1mb-2mb each. I also need to send some metadata along with this so am using Multipart/form-data to send both the list of files + some data. I can't use external service such as AWS or Azure so my limitation is sending to an API that accepts these files.

Most of the progress logic I saw was server-side (i.e. blazor server opening stream on file, copying to a filestream through a buffer and updating progress bar based on bytes read). The client side logic I saw was mostly meant for large files which is chunked and each chunk uploaded individually (e.g. https://github.com/agency8/BlazorFileUploadApp).

Is there a way to do this on small files where you don't need to break the file into small chunks as they will only be about 2mb or less in size?

Currently I am doing below:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var memoryStream  = new MemoryStream();

//loop through each file uploaded
//foreach(file in filesUploaded)
using var stream = file.OpenReadSteam(maxAllowSize: //set to 2mb)
int read = 0;
var buffer = new byte[4096];

while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer)) > 0)
{
   //uploadedBytes is used to keep track of progress bar by comparing it to total size to determine %uploaded
   uploadedBytes += read;
   await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0,read));
}

var contentToLoad = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
content.add(byteArrayContent, "filesToUpload", file.name);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

//after looping through all files
httpclient.post(content);
```

I know you can do following directly instead of reading a file into memory:

```
var contentToAdd = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
content.Add(contentToAdd, "filesToUpload", file.Name);
```

Only issue with above is I can't get progress on files processed.

Question here is how I can improve upon this? Everything works but I am not 100% on if this is the correct approach. Couple things I notice is reading a file into a memory stream and converting that to a bytearray both of which add overhead. Is the 2nd approach of adding StreamContent much better? If so how would you get a progress % to work with that?

I'm not entirely sure how httpclient handles multipart/form-data so wanted to ask the best way to capture progress on smaller files is. Not sure if internally the files get chunked and streamed up or if they are also read into memory before being sent along in the request. I know blazor wasm uses fetch API underneath the httpclient implementation. Does fetch stream files up when using multipart/form-data or read entire file into memory during upload?

Comment: @shingo That link relies on stream handling the link from there relies on multi threading which WASM has issues with re browser support.

Comment: That answer doesn't involve multithreading.

Comment: @shingo I was able to get that to work by utilizing a custom httpcontent. Question about it - is it better than the original approach? My assumption is regardless of if I was reading into a memorystream, when the request was sent via httpclient, it is running the SerializetoStream in order to send the content. Does the solution you suggested essentially take over that process so I can enable invoking a delegate as needed during the serialization process? Struggling to understand how httpclient utilizes streams so it'd be good to know.

Comment: Yes, regardless of the type of content you use, you can see that the httpclient finally writes the content to an internal stream.